# Como fazer comparação de arrays?

Tags: php

Estou com dificuldades de fazer esta questão:

Faça um programa que receba dez idades, pesos e alturas e que calcule e mostre:

- A quantidade de pessoas com peso superior a 90 quilos e altura inferior a 1,50;
- A percentagem de pessoas com idade entre 10 e 30 anos entre as pessoas que medem mais de 1,90;

Eu criei três input's para receber as informações (idade, peso e altura). No PHP elas são inseridas em um array através do explode, mas não consigo relacionar os arrays de peso e altura para responder ao primeiro ponto nem relacionar os arrays de idade e altura para responder o segundo ponto.

Código que tenho até agora:

```
<form action="" method="post">

    <label for="idade">Idade</label>
    <input type="text" name="idade">

    <label for="peso">Peso</label>
    <input type="text" name="peso">

    <label for="altura">Altura</label>
    <input type="text" name="altura">


    <input type="submit" name="enviar">
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['enviar'])){

$cont = 0;
$soma = 0;
$media = 0;

$idades = explode(",", $_POST['idade']);
$pesos = explode(",", $_POST['peso']);
$alturas = explode(",", $_POST['altura']);

?>
```

Comment: Você já viu como ficam os arrays? Experimente ver que vai perceber como ficam associadas as informações.

Comment: Com `array_filter` você consegue remover do array elementos que não satisfazem certa condição.

Answer (score 1):

Uma dica é você e trabalhar com os índices do array, pois pelo que entendi cada posição do array vai ser uma pessoa (posição 1 == pessoa 1) , por exemplo

```
for($i=0;$i<=10;$i++)
{
  if ($peso[i] > 90) && ($altura[i] < 1,50)
  {
   $count++;//se a pessoa tiver mais que 90kg **E** tiver menos que 1,50 de altura incrimento +1 no meu contador
  }
}
```

Comment: `$count = $count++;` é redundante, apenas `$count++;` é o suficiente

Comment: De fato , vou fazer esse alteração.
Obrigado pelo aviso.